# How many monitors support the Radeon hd 6870 eyefinity with Ubuntu?

Tags: multiple-monitors, radeon, dvi

how many monitors the Radeon hd 6870 eyefinity supports with the latest version of Ubuntu?

At the moment I have 4 monitors configuration connected to these ports:

- 2 Dvi
- 2 minidv with dvi adapter

I have read about the MST DISPLAYPORT connection but I don't know if it works in Ubuntu. This is the device:

[image]

This is my workspace:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30067/eyefinity-across-3-displays-with-a-amd-radeon-6800), Ubuntu handles multiple monitors well, so you should be good to upgrade. According to [the docs](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide#Dual.2FMulti_Monitors), you should run this after upgrading catalyst:

```
sudo amdconfig --initial -f
sudo amdconfig --set-pcs-str="DDX,EnableRandR12,FALSE"
```

Comment: hi Ian thanks for the answer but I don't understand from the graphic card docs how to connect over 4 monitors.

Comment: You need to use the DisplayPort connection, AFAIK. I don't know if this is supported in Ubuntu.